# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я совсем недавно начал изучать Python и пока что плохо его знаю. Решил поделать задания в интернете. Вот код к одному из них:

```
word = input('Type a word: ').split()
letters = [int(i) for i in word if i % 2 == 0]
print(letters)
```

После ввода слова вылетает следующая ошибка:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Можете помочь мне?

Comment: Операция `%`, применённая к строке, означает форматирование - подстановку значений в эту строку, например `'число %d!' % 2` даст в результате `число 2!`. Вы же пытаетесь применить эту операцию к строке, в которой нет никаких %d и %s, вот питон и жалуется, что не все аргументы были подставлены в строку.

Comment: Если вы думали, что это получение остатка от деления, то остатка от деления строки не бывает по причине бессмысленности.

Answer (score 1):

Метод `split()` разбивает строку на список.

Метод `strip()` удаляет все начальные (пробелы в начале) 
и конечные (пробелы в конце) символы (пробел является ведущим символом по умолчанию для удаления)

Функция `enumerate()` принимает коллекцию и возвращает ее как объект перечисления. 
Функция `enumerate()` добавляет счетчик в качестве ключа объекта перечисления.

```
#word = input('Type a word: ').split()
word = input('Type a word: ').strip()

#letters = [int(i) for i in word if i % 2 == 0]
letters = [l for i, l in enumerate(word) if i % 2 == 0]

print(letters)
```